# Java Web3j - How to solve the error `invalid sender`?

Tags: ether, web3j, sendtransaction

I am web3j beginner. Now I am trying to send transaction and faced this error: `invalid sender`. It's related credentials, I think.

```
ECKeyPair keyPair = walletService.keysFromWallet(password, walletAddress);
        if (keyPair == null) {
            log.error("Error getting keys from wallet");
            return null;
        }
        Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(keyPair);
```

And the keysFronWallet is following.

```
    public ECKeyPair keysFromWallet(String password, String address) throws WalletNotFoundException {
            byte[] entropy = this.entropyFromWallet(password, address);
    
            // Create new key pair
            ECKeyPair keyPair = bip39Service.credentialsFromEntropy(entropy).getEcKeyPair();
  return keyPair;
    }
```

Here the `entropyFromWallet` is just return the entropy. it has not problem. And.

```
public Credentials credentialsFromEntropy(byte[] entropy) {
        try {
            // Generate a BIP32 master keypair from the seed
            Bip32ECKeyPair masterKeypair = Bip32ECKeyPair.generateKeyPair(entropy);

            // Derive the key path for the first account (m/44'/60'/0'/0/0)
            // BIP44 derivation path for the first Ethereum account
            int[] derivationPath = { 44 | 0x80000000, 60 | 0x80000000, 0 | 0x80000000, 0, 0 };
            Bip32ECKeyPair derivedKeyPair = Bip32ECKeyPair.deriveKeyPair(masterKeypair, derivationPath);

            // Create credentials
            Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(derivedKeyPair);

            return credentials;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why this error occurs. Above codes have no mistake. This error came from wrong chain Id. After using the correct chain id, the error is disappeared.